# TeamViewer only has one resolution

Tags: windows-10, teamviewer

I have a desktop PC that I access using a laptop, both running Windows 10. My laptop has a 4K monitor that I set to display at 1920x1080 because 4K on windows causes the GUI to be a mess.

When I remote control my desktop through LAN, Teamviewer only has 1 screen resolution to pick from, 1920x1080, whereas using other laptops in the past I had many different options. This is a problem because I really don't need the high res, and the bad wifi connection can't keep up with it.

How do I set it to a lower resolution?

Answer (score 1):

On the tab that appears at the top of teamviewer select the "View" option

From there you can change the Resolution

[image]

Comment: That was my question actually, there's only one option there

Comment: What option is that?

Comment: 1920x1080 under Optimal screen resolution, none under Other screen resolutions

Comment: Try updating the graphic drivers on your machine, if that doesn't work id recommend updating them on the machine you are logging into, i usually get a whacky resolution when logging into a machine that requires a graphics driver update.